# Node.js listener definition

Tags: node.js, listener

how would you definte listeners in node.js?

They are event emitter objects that listen for certain events to occur and then notify the event emitter or call a callback function?

any help is appreciated

Comment: A listener is a function that is invoked when a particular event occurs, typically with an event object containing information about the event.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Event Emitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

Here is a simple example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}

const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

myEmitter.on('someCoolEvent', () => { // Here is where we are listening for event to occur
  console.log('an event occurred!');
});


myEmitter.emit('someCoolEvent'); // here is how we emit the event
```